# How to stop the CountDownTimer?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

where should I edit this code, that i can stop the CountDown ?

How to delete the old one before I start the next new CountDown ?

```js
public void MyCounter1(){
        new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 txt_timer.setText("Left time : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);                         
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                txt_timer.setText("done");
            }
        }.start();

    }
```

Comment: Cut the blue wire!

Comment: ...are you sure it isn't the red wire @hobbs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is code:

```
   CountDownTimer timer= null;
            public void MyCounter1(){
                timer =new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        txt_timer.setText("Left time : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    }
                    public void onFinish() {
                        txt_timer.setText("done");
                    }
                };
                timer.start();

            }

// To stop & start new timer check not null of timer instance first then cancel existing timer & start new one
            if(timer  != null){
                timer.cancel();
                 MyCounter1();
            }
```

also if you want to cancel first instance and start new one you can add above lines in onFinish method which will be get called when timer finish his time.
check this:

```
CountDownTimer timer= null;
         public void MyCounter1(){
                            timer =new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                    txt_timer.setText("Left time : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                                }
                                public void onFinish() {
                                    txt_timer.setText("done");
                                     if(timer  != null){
                                        timer.cancel();
                                         MyCounter1();
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                            timer.start();

                        }
```

Comment: I did not see your answer before, I think your code is better as my solution below, because my code check every Second `if(my_condition==1)`  to contenue, which is not needed. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did these 2 lines. I works at  the time fine:

```
public void MyCounter1(){
        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 if(my_condition=1){  //1- just make my_condition<>1 to stop  the counter
                 txt_timer.setText("Left time : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);  }                       
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                countDownTimer.cacel(); // 2- delete old one
                txt_timer.setText("done");
            }
        }.start();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int time = 10; //example 10 min.    

CountDownTimer(60000 *  time, 1000)

 @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                txt_timer.setText("done");
                 cancel();
                time = 0;
```

Comment: please add explanations to your answer